# No higher than vs not higher than

Tags: comparatives, comparisons

I came across this weird uncommon usage in a documentation page.
Can anyone help me understand the meaning/stipulation here?

It says "value x can be **no higher than** "some value"

Does it mean that "**x**" should be less than this value ??
I have seen similar usage like No More than and others but couldn't find this particular one anywhere.

It would be wonderful too if someone can get a link to something concrete to set things beyond doubt about the meaning of the usage

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Hello, logrish. This question is not suitable for ELU, so I will close-vote.

Comment: Sorry, but i am not sure about the issue involved... should i remove the technical part of the question? I was curious about the usage of No Higher than and Not higher than... had never come across it before. Do le me know if i should modify the question.

Comment: Have you read this introduction to the site: _English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts._? The question is reasonable, but ELU is not intended for such basic questions. There are **many** other websites that are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost correct. "No higher than 17" means "less than or equal to 17", so in the example specified an app with minSdkVersion of 17 would be acceptable.

Comment: So anything less than or equal to 17 is acceptable... thanks :)